# How can I replace a key-value pair in a nested dictionary with the value from the same key-value pair?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, replace, nested, key-value

I want to replace the key-value pair in a directory with the value from the same key-value pair. In simple words, I want to replace

`{k1:{key1:value1},k2:{Key2:value2}} with {k1:value1,k2:value2}`

in simple words: `{key1:value1}` gets replaced with value1

```
My input is {'times': {0: 3284566678.449864},
 'C0PLUSA': {0: 2.4529042386185244e-06},
 'C1PLUSA': {0: 2.215571719760855e-06},
 'I0PLUSA': {0: 1200.000000000029},
 'M1BA': {0: 1.1971391933999447e-05},
 'M1DA': {0: 2.5217060699404884e-06},
 'M1GA': {0: 1.0922075194286918e-05},
 'M1SA': {0: 0.0006776339108859284},
 'M2BA': {0: 1.7152638293476106e-05}}
```

Code:

```
for i, key,value in a.items:
    a[key][value] = value.values()
```

But I get an error saying this object is not iterable.

```
for node,value in a.items():
    a = a.replace(node.values(), value.values())
```

but it still gives me an error.

I am expecting to get an output as:

```
{'times':3284566678.449864,
     'C0PLUSA': 2.4529042386185244e-06,
     'C1PLUSA': 2.215571719760855e-06,
     'I0PLUSA': 1200.000000000029,
     'M1BA':  1.1971391933999447e-05,
     'M1DA':  2.5217060699404884e-06,
     'M1GA':  1.0922075194286918e-05,
     'M1SA':  0.0006776339108859284,
     'M2BA':  1.7152638293476106e-05}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the keys in the inner dictionaries are `0` you can just do:

```
{k:v[0] for k,v in data.items()}
```

In case you want to ignore the keys of the inner dictionaries without knowing the value, you can see how this example works:

```
>>> data={'k1': {'key1': 'value1'}, 'k2': {'key2': 'value2'}}
>>> {k:list(v.values())[0] for k,v in data.items()}
{'k1': 'value1', 'k2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: Thank you jacalvo it works perfectly fine for this case. Could I please  ask  for an explanation for this .  if my inner dictionary had different keys, then what would work for it. Thanks for your time and help

Comment: You are welcome. I've edited the answer with a more generic example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot jacalvo. Appreciate your help.